# Share Instagram story from webapp

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I'm trying to figure out how to copy an image to Instagram Stories, like the feature in Spotify.  But in a webapp.

I'm executing this javascript before copying an image to clipboard:

> const urlInstagram = 'instagram-stories://share'
> window.location.href = urlInstagram;

[BlackImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnU15.jpg)

When it redirects to Instagram, asks the user if they want to allow copying from Safari, and then opens the story.

However, the image that is displayed is black.

Do you have any ideas for implementing this feature in a webapp?

Cheers.

I tried a lot of codes without lucky.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.